# TinyMCE Popup overlay color and popup autoresize

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I was wondering how I could set the color for the popup overlay (which is now white).
And I was wondering if it's possible to set the popup to autoresize to popups content.

**Additional question**

Is it possible to resize the popup if the content changes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [resizeToInnerSize](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aAPI/tinyMCEPopup/resizeToInnerSize) of tinyMCEPopup to autoresize to the popups content.

To change the overlay color you may use:

- modify the background attribute in http://yourserver.com/tiny_mce/plugins/inlinepopups/skins/clearlooks2/window.css (maybe this css can be overridden using the editor_content.css init setting)
- using jQuery: `$('#mceModalBlocker').css('background','#FA00BB');`

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: The pointer to the dialog css is wonderful, was looking for that! So Thanks a lot! About the resizing of the dialogs, the resizeToInnerSize is already in a lot of plugins, but doesn't work unfortunately...

Comment: maybe this functionality is a little bit out outdated, in my plugins i just set the size per hand

Comment: I'm changing the media plugin so only video's can be entered, and wanted the dialog to resize whenever the preview changed, so on big values the preview would be completely visible in the dialog, a feature that fancybox has, but I'm thinking that it's not possible in tinyMCE. It's not that big of a deal, and I can set it on the standard preview size. You really helped me out with pointing to the dialog css file (never thought that was a plugin!) so thanks!